# How to isolate the UI processes for projects in vs-code, so if one window crashes it doesn't affect unrelated projects running in other windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

*This is question is primarily about running vs-code in Linux*

Sometimes vs-studio crashes, for instance an editor could be hang on a bug or a search in an unlimited terminal takes forever, an open folder requester is still open when its main window is closed. In all those cases vs-code crashes and must be restated. It mostly get up to the same state as before but not quite. This is extra problematic when some of the windows are used to start long running jobs.

I would like all my projects (e.g. Open Folder, Open Workspace etc) to be running in an individual instance of vs-code, so if one crashes it doesn't kill the other. Could this be achieved?